# Zen Coding, how to achieve alternating item multiplication

Tags: html, emmet

I recently attempted adding [Zen Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Coding) to my tool box of software development box of magic and have been mostly underwhelmed by it. Whether or not this is because it truly is technically deficient or rather suffers from documentation deficiencies I am not sure. Regardless, I can't seem to use Zen Coding to generate this very simple and commonly occurring HTML pattern that emerges when working with forms

```
<div id="region1">    
    <h1></h1>
    <div class="data-label">
    </div>
    <div class="data-value">
    </div>
    <div class="data-label">
    </div>
    <div class="data-value">
    </div>
    <div class="data-label">
    </div>
    <div class="data-value">
    </div>    
</div>
```

Is is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is currently not possible. There is an [open ticket](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/issues/detail?id=155) on this very issue at [Zen coding's repository page](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/).

Your expression should look something like this:

```
div#region1>(h1+(div.data-label+div.data-value)*3)
```

But as you write it does not work.

Comment: Good news - the code fix/update has been committed to github I think we will see a release soon. https://github.com/sergeche/zen-coding/commit/8bd7475332d22465235bf47f5a3709464c4fb97f#diff-5